# Getting error while adding shared_preferences to flutter app

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences

I created new flutter project along with androidx support and trying add shared_preferences 0.5.4+3. when i call get command. it is giving message like The plugin `shared_preferences` requires your app to be migrated to the Android embedding v2. Follow the steps on https://flutter.dev/go/android-project-migration and re-run this command.

When i do the changes described in the above, app is not launching and giving error like below.

```
.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_preferences-0.5.4+3/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/sharedpreferences/SharedPreferencesPlugin.java:25: warning: [deprecation] getFlutterEngine() in FlutterPluginBinding has been deprecated
    setupChannel(binding.getFlutterEngine().getDartExecutor(), binding.getApplicationContext());
```

Comment: Use the latest [shared_pref](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences)

Answer (score 5):

Just change or add in your pubspec.yaml file

```
shared_preferences: ^0.5.3+5
```

Answer (score 0):

Open android/app/src/main/java/[your.package.name]/MainActivity.java.
Change the existing code

```
package [your.package.name];
import android.os.Bundle;
import io.flutter.app.FlutterActivity;
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;
public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this);
}}
```

to

```
package [your.package.name];
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity;
public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity { }
```

Open android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml.
Remove all  tags with key android:name="io.flutter.app.android.SplashScreenUntilFirstFrame".
Add a new  tag under  with content

```
<meta-data
android:name="flutterEmbedding"
android:value="2" />
```

Your app should still build as normal (such as via flutter build apk) but you're now using the new Android classes.

Comment: what if you use kotlin instead of java?

Comment: otherwise revert your share_preference version  shared_preferences: '0.5.1+2'  it will work

Comment: @SubaharanVel Can you reference any documentation on recommending this change going forward?

Comment: nm.  Found it here:  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Upgrading-pre-1.12-Android-projects

Answer (score 0):

Revert your share_preference version to shared_preferences: '0.5.1+2' it will work

Answer (score 0):

shared_preferences: ^0.5.6

1. **Install** **[OpenJDK11U-jdk_x64_windows_hotspot_11.0.6_10.msi](https://github-production-release-asset-2e65be.s3.amazonaws.com/140419044/0de6e500-37b7-11ea-8537-c07fd09680fd?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIWNJYAX4CSVEH53A%2F20200123%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20200123T042248Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signature=a24fe6fe66269c0dea66a0eff0b62d913eaddec9375c538ddf37bd8d9e476cf4&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&actor_id=46811138&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3DOpenJDK11U-jdk_x64_windows_hotspot_11.0.6_10.msi&response-content-type=application%2Foctet-stream)**.
2. **Run** *flutter build apk --release*

*Its working for me.*

***Happy Coding!!!***

Comment: Hello sweetnadaha cse, welcome to StackOverflow! Please do not hotlink files, due to link decay. In fact, your link already decayed and is no longer usable. It is recommended to link the download page instead of the actual file so anybody can review the site and file credibility before downloading anything. (Please don't misunderstand, I don't want to accuse you of spreading malware but hotlinking a file is a common way to spread it)